# Enter in alert message triggers function again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I'm working with angular for the first time, and I made this - http://tweeny.herokuapp.com/

Go there and enter nothing, and hit enter, there will be an alert, hit enter again to close the alert, and it reopens the alert. However, closing the alert with mouse click works just fine. How do I bypass it?

I trigger `enter` here:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="screenName" class="username" autofocus required ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? getTweet(screenName) : null">
```

which goes into [app.js](https://github.com/karan/What-Would-I-Tweet/blob/master/static/app.js). I am not sure what I should change.

Comment: It works fine for me. I hit enter and it pops up. I hit enter once more it closes.

Comment: What browser are you on? On chrome it's not fine for me.

Comment: Chromium here too.But this does't work on Firefox

Comment: Chrome on mac is the only one doing this.